# What sensors are commonly used for vehicle detection?

Tags: infrared, automotive, inductive, magnetics, ultrasound

I want to make a vehicle detection prototype. I find there are multiple choices of sensors that can be used to detect a vehicle, such as acoustic, ultrasonic, infrared, magnetic inductive sensor.

I am only familiar with infrared sensors, which are low cost, can be a good choice of detection of approaching objects, whereas the acoustic and ultrasonic are much more expensive.

However an infrared sensor is not a complete solution. In order to find whether the approaching object is either a vehicle or any other objects, I suppose I need either a magnetic or an inductive sensor. I learned that scalar magnetometers are suitable for the vehicle detection, because it measure the total strength of the magnetic field to which they are subjected.  However then I learned that magnetic sensors can be also divided into DC and AC sensors.

> in wiki, it says "AC" if they measure fields that vary relatively
>   rapidly in time, and "DC" if they measure fields that vary only slowly
>   (quasi-static) or are static. AC magnetometers find use in
>   electromagnetic systems (such as magnetotellurics), and DC
>   magnetometers are used for detecting mineralisation and corresponding
>   geological structures.

Can anybody explain the difference between DC and AC based magnetometers? Currently my idea is to use a magnetometer with an infrared sensor. What do you think of this approach? My evaluation criteria is performance first, then power consumption, and cost last.

Comment: Vehicle detection???Do you hate Image processing???

Comment: Have you tried searching for information?

Comment: I am now still searching the information on web, to compare different sensors. I am just seeking some more ideas if someone has experience on them. I only worked on the infrared sensor.

Comment: I am not hating image processing for vehicle detection. However, image processing is kind of costly than the sensor based solution, and I don't want to be offensive to the privacy issue. while image processing solution works on the indoor, I hope to have a sensor based solution on the outdoor . if you know about the streetline or worldsensing, they are using the WSN to detect the vehicle.

Comment: @user824624: It would help if you clarify what exactly you mean by "detection". Detecting a vehicle's absolute position tracked within an area vs. Detecting when a vehicle passes through a specific area/gateway vs. Detecting when a vehicle comes in proximity of a vehicle

Comment: @perilbrain, are you saying that image processing is a clear winner over, say, a metal detector, for basic detection of a giant lump of metal? How would you assess the development costs and unit costs in those two approaches?

Answer (score 1):

"Vehicle detection loops, called inductive-loop traffic detectors" are one pretty common method. A groove is cut in the pavement, wire is layed in the groove, the groove is filled in with a sealant, and the wires go to a processor which makes the wire act like a metal detector - the vehicle interacts with the e-mag field, and the processor detects that.

Are you allowed to sawcut the area in question? If not, then a different method should be selected.  Maybe just tubes across the road as one finds leading into or out of a town so the local municipality can count how many cars are using a road.  I imagine they just detect change in air pressure as cars drive over the tubes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much on this subject but I found...
https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/publicroads/07nov/04.cfm 
Sounds like inductive sensors are the most common currently. 
I don't know where it stands today, but years ago there was interesting research into smart concrete that could detect vehicle weight and location. 
e.g. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1999/05/990520073311.htm